# data.table alternative to piping

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I'm currently learning the very robust and efficient data.table framework(package). I however can't seem to figure out how to do something like this. 
What I'm looking to do is group by multiple columns(manufacturer and carier), get the number of flights based on this grouping then arrange these in descending order followed by a ggplot of the top 10 manufacturers and carriers. 
I would do this in the tidyverse as follows:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)
flights %>% 
  left_join(planes, by = "tailnum") %>% 
  group_by(manufacturer, carrier) %>% 
  summarise(N = n()) %>% 
  arrange(desc(N)) %>% 
  top_n(10, N) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(carrier, N, fill = manufacturer)) + geom_col() + guides(fill = FALSE)
```

Here is what I've tried:(I left the question for several minutes to try and solve it but failed)

```
library(data.table)
fly<-copy(nycflights13::flights)
setDT(fly)
setkey(fly,tailnum)
planes1 <- copy(planes)
setDT(planes1)
setkey(planes1, tailnum)
#head(planes1,2)
Merged <- merge(fly, planes1, by = "tailnum")
#Group by manufacturer
Merged[, .N, by = .(manufacturer,carrier)] #[, order(manufacturer, carrier)]
```

The problem is I can't get to return the ordered data and also don't know how to "chain" to ggplot without saving the ordered merge as an object first.

Comment: Maybe better luck on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Henrik edited. Please let me know if I need to make it more clear.

Comment: @Roman Thanks. I'll see if someone helps in a couple of hours. If not, I'll try Code Review as I continue to try myself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the square brackets `[` & `]` to chain stuff together in [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table). Furthermore, you can execute a `ggplot` call inside the `j` part of the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) syntax:

```
nms <- setdiff(names(planes1), "tailnum")

fly[planes1, on = .(tailnum), (nms) := mget(nms)
    ][, .N, by = .(manufacturer,carrier)
      ][order(-N)
        ][, .SD[1:10], by = .(manufacturer,carrier)
          ][, ggplot(.SD, aes(carrier, N, fill = manufacturer)) +
              geom_col() +
              guides(fill = FALSE)]
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Just a note here. The above graphic is not reproducible with the bare code above it. It would be nice to make sure the code presented is wholly reproducible.